# How To Close signinPopup() Window After Identity Server Authentication oidc-client Angular

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an Angular App that I'm needing to authenticate user through Identity Server 4. I'm using the signinPopup() method on the UserManager. This works as designed. When I launch the login, it opens the popup window and the login form.

Login is successful, but instead of closing the popUp window and the login claims info being passed to the "opener" window, it just loads the post_login_redirect_uri within the popup window.

I need it to close this window and then that data be available to the application that launched the signinPopup, not within the popup itself.

And, if I manually close that window, the data still doesn't get passed back to the main (initiator of popup) window. Catches error instead.

I have been researching and found a couple posts about how to do this, but nothing descriptive. I don't think editing the Identity Server login code to handle closing a popup is the "correct" way to do this.

Can someone help with this?

```
//THis launches popup and authentication is successful. 
startSigninPopup(){

this.mgr.signinPopup().then((user) =>{
  console.log(user);
  return user;
}).catch((error) => {
 // if manually closing the popup, I end up in catch with error.
  console.log(error)
})
```

}

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question and found a clue within the sample code on the oidc-client's github

In this sample, the signinPopup() is redirecting to a page which simply calls [new Oidc.UserManager().signinPopupCallback();](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/26a45b61f1371b53c10100283997946c63d88f83/samples/VanillaJS/public/user-manager-sample-popup-signin.js#L3)

This closes the pop-up and resolves the promise from the parent page successfully.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts/blob/866a75acfd8e44868144881e14bd874d69b84901/samples/Parcel/src/user-manager/sample-popup-signin.js#L4

Answer (score 0):

It might as simple as using popup_redirect_uri instead of post_login_redirect_uri.  See https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki